# Convert from Bezier surfaces RIB file into something Blender can import?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, conversion

Can anybody recommend a free converter that’ll turn a Bezier surfaces RIB file into a mesh format that Blender can import? I have [a RIB file of Ed Catmull's "Gumbo"](https://prideout.net/blog/old/blog/index.html@p=46.html) that I’d like to use in Blender.

I'd also be fine with a version of Ed Catmull’s “Gumbo” already converted into something Blender can import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Teapot+ bit of Blender's included Extra Objects addon, add_mesh_teapot.py by Anthony D’Agostino, uses the same kind of bicubic patch data.  Took some work, but I used it to get mesh:

[image: Gumbo the Elephant]

For anyone interested, more details and a blend download in [the topic at BlenderArtists.](https://blenderartists.org/t/ed-catmulls-gumbo-the-elephant/1349602)