# Loop Cut Indicator Color - Preferences Settings in 3.0?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edit-mode, customization

The Loop Cut & Slide indicator line (in the 3D viewport, in Edit mode) changes color with some themes, so it has a setting in Preferences, but I haven’t been able to find it.  Also checked [the Preferences part of the 3.0 manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/index.html), no joy.

Here’s some examples of a proposed loopcut on the back of Suzanne’s head in four of Blender’s included themes:

[image]

Should be simple, right? Edit > Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport, it’s gotta be one of the color controls that’s yellow in the default theme (Blender Dark), black in Blender’s Maya theme, and blue in Blender’s Modo & XSI themes. But I’m not finding it.

Comment: Excellent job on posting your first question mate!

Comment: @HISEROD - Thanks, but it's my second question here.  [My first one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210683/convert-from-bezier-surfaces-rib-file-into-something-blender-can-import) was less successful though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Axis and Gizmo Colors

The Loop Cut tool's preview lines are considered a gizmo internally.

To find the theme color for this one, go to *User Preferences → Themes → User Interface → Axis and Gizmo Colors → Gizmo Primary.*

[image: 1]

Comment: man that's a one big hat you've got there! :))

Comment: @JachymMichal Why thank you. :D