What is this line called in the custom options panel
Can someone please tell me where this line color is located?


Tell us how you created the line and we might be able to help!

@JohnEason I think it's from loop cut

Its the loop cut line.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247547/loop-cut-indicator-color-preferences-settings-in-3-0

@HarryMcKenzie I realised that eventually and a quick google provided the answer from BSE! - See my link comment above. Hmm... That setting seems to be missing in Blender 4!

So this line is a Gizmo, thanks for the link.
